# O que são os termos Weak Entity, Weak Relationship e One Optional/Mandatory?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, modelagem, relacionamento

Estou usando uma ferramento online [yEd Live](https://www.yworks.com/yed-live/) para modelar um diagrama MER. Entretanto, há alguns elementos que usam uns termos no qual me deixam com algumas dúvidas.

Esses termos são:

- WeakEntity (retângulo)
- WeakRelationship (losango)
- One Optional (seta para representar cardinalidade)
- One Mandatory (seta para representar cardinalidade)

## Pergunta

Portanto, eu gostaria de saber o que são esses termos e quais as diferenças entre eles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WeakEntity

É a entidade que não pode existir por si própria, ela sempre depende da existência de outra entidade que a sustente, que a associe. O exemplo clássico é a linha de item de uma nota fiscal, ela sozinha não pode existir, ela depende da existência de uma nota fiscal que ela esteja associada. Ela exige um relacionamento forte.

> WeakRelationship

É o relacionamento entre entidades fortes, portanto que podem existir sozinhas, então só precisa de uma identificação simples do que relacionar. Um aluno com um curso por exemplo, eles estão relacionados quando há interesse em ambos, caso contrário o relacionamento não é necessário.

> One Optional

Significa que o relacionamento poderá ter zero ou uma entidade ligada. O zero indica a opcionalidade e fica claro que não pode ter mais que um.

> One Mandatory

Significa que o relacionamento precisa de uma entidade ligada, mas só uma, não mais.

Comment: a resposta do weak relationship esta toltamente errada, o correto 'e a relacao de uma entity com uma weak entity, e um exemplo seria uma tabela pessoa e uma tipo de sangue, tipo de sangue precisa de pessoa para existir, na pratica a week relationship so vai ter a id de pessoa e a id do tipo de sangue, caso ela tenha outros valores ela deixa de ser uma week relationship ou ate mesmo uma week entity